# R - Multi-level list indexing

Tags: r, list

**What is the convention to assign an object to a multi-level list?**

Sofar I thought the convention [1](https://www.listendata.com/2015/10/how-to-use-indexing-operators-in-list.html),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091202/how-to-index-an-element-of-a-list-object-in-r) of indexing is to use `[[]]` instead of `$`.

Hence, when saving results in loops I usually used the following approach:

```
> result <- matrix(2,2,2)

> result_list <- list()
> result_list[["A"]][["B"]][["C"]] <- result
> print(result_list)
$A
$A$B
$A$B$C
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    2    2
```

Which works as intended with this matrix.
But when assigning a single number the list seems to skip the last level.

```
> result <- 2
> result_list <- list()
> result_list[["A"]][["B"]][["C"]] <- result
> print(result_list)
$A
B 
2
```

At the same time, if I use `$` instead of `[[]]` the list again is as intendet.

```
> result_list$A$B$C <- result
> print(result_list)
$A
$A$B
$A$B$C
[1] 2
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434268/multi-level-lists-in-r)  you can also use `list("A" = list("B" = list("C" = 2)))`.

**Which of these methods should be used for indexing a multi-level list in R?**

Comment: I can *not* confirm this behaviour. I get all the time the same list structure. What version are you using (4.0.0)?

Comment: I *can* confirm this anomaly on version 3.6.2. Yet I don't know why this happens

Comment: I use Version 3.6.3

Comment: I guess this behaviour could be linked to a [recent change in R-4.0.0](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/f3de035e12a8c8920772297405ed25ee6b3ec4a6/doc/NEWS.Rd#L398), regarding the behaviour of assigning a `length == 1` vector to a `NULL` list element (here, your `result_list[["A"]]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the title of the question referst to multi-level list *indexing*, and the syntax `mylist[['a']][['b']][['c']]` is the same that one would use to retrieve an element of a multi-level list, the differences that you're observing actually arise from using the same syntax for *creation* (or not) of multi-level lists.

To show this, we can first explicitly create the multi-level (nested) lists, and then check that the indexing works as expected both for matrices and for single numbers.

```
mymatrix=matrix(1:4,nrow=2)
list_b=list(c=mymatrix)
list_a=list(b=list_b)
mynestedlist1=list(a=list_a)
str( mynestedlist1 )
# List of 1
#  $ a:List of 1
#   ..$ b:List of 1
#   .. ..$ c: int [1:2, 1:2] 1 2 3 4

mynumber=2
list_e=list(f=mynumber)
list_d=list(e=list_e)
mynestedlist2=list(d=list_d)
str( mynestedlist2 )
# List of 1
#  $ d:List of 1
#   ..$ e:List of 1
#   .. ..$ f: num 2
```

( Note that I've created the lists in sequential steps for clarity; the could have been all rolled-together in a single line, like: `mynestedlist2=list(d=list(e=list(f=mynumber)))` )

Anyway, now we'll check that indexing works Ok:

```
str(mynestedlist1[['a']][['b']][['c']])
# int [1:2, 1:2] 1 2 3 4
str(mynestedlist1$a$b$c)
# int [1:2, 1:2] 1 2 3 4

str(mynestedlist2[['d']][['e']][['f']])
# num 2
str(mynestedlist2$d$e$f)
# num 2

# and, just to check that we don't 'skip the last level':
str(mynestedlist2[['d']][['e']])
# List of 1
#  $ f: num 2
```

So the direct answer to the question 'which of these methods should be used for indexing a multi-level list in R' is: **'any of them - they're all ok'**.

So what's going on with the examples in the question, then?

Here, the same syntax is being used to try to implicitly *create* lists, and since the structure of the nested list is not specified explicitly, this relies on whether R can infer the structure that you want.

In the first and third examples, there's no ambiguity, but each for a different reason:

First example:

```
mynestedlist1=list()
mynestedlist1[['a']][['b']][['c']]=mymatrix
```

We've specified that `mynestedlist1` is a list.  But its elements could be any kind of object, until we assign them.  In this case, we put into the element named `'a'` an object with an element `'b'` that contains an object with an element `'c'` that is a matrix.  Since there's no R object that can contain a matrix in a single element except a list, the only way to achieve this assignment is by creating a nested list.

Third example:

```
mynestedlist3=list()
mynestedlist3$g$h$i=mynumber
```

In this case, we've used the `$` notation, which only applies to lists (or to data types that are similar/equivalent to lists, like dataframes).  So, again, the only way to follow the instructions of this assignment is by creating a nested list.

Finally, the pesky second example, but starting with a simpler variant of it:

```
mylist2=list()
mylist2[['c']][['d']]=mynumber
```

Here there's an ambiguity.  We've specified that `mylist2` is a list, and we've put into the element named `'c'` an object with an element `'d'` that contains a single number.  This element could have been a list, but it can also be a simple vector, and in this case R chooses this as the simpler option:

```
str(mylist2)
# List of 1
#  $ c: Named num 2
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "d"
```

Contrast this to the behaviour when trying to assign a matrix using exactly the same syntax: in this case, the only way follow the syntax would be by creating another, nested, list inside the first one.

What about the full second example `mylist2[['c']][['d']][['e']]=mynumber`, where we try to assign a number named `'e'` to the just-created but still-empty object `'d'`?
This seems rather unclear, and this may be the reason for the different behaviours of different versions of R (as reported in the comments to the question).  In the question, the action taken by R has been to assign the number while dropping its name, similarly to:

```
myvec=vector(); myvec2=vector()
myvec[['a']]=1
myvec2[['b']]=2
myvec[['a']]=myvec2
str(myvec)
#  Named num 2
#  - attr(*, "names")= chr "a"
```

However, the syntax alone doesn't seem to force this behaviour, so it would be sensible to avoid relying on this behaviour when trying to *create* nested lists, or lists of vectors.